# How is the parable of the Rich Man and Lazarus interpreted?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-luke, afterlife, parables

I have always been puzzled by this in Scripture.

Can someone clarify these points:

If Jesus was speaking of reality then 'The End' had technically already come. Is this correct?

From Hell it would appear we can see Heaven and speak to people in Heaven as they can see us.

The last point I have comes from Revelation.  We are taught that in the end everyone will live on earth.  It speaks that the pure and holy will walk past those who are un-pure and un-holy day after day to worship.

It also states that there are gates to Heaven which again have people outside them.  Can I assume then that Hell is basically everything outside of Heavens gates.

Why would Heaven even need gates?

Comment: Please separate this into distinct questions and add the relevant scriptures.

Comment: Well @DJClayworth is right about the description of the parable (by definition it is). But the most interesting part of this parable is the revelation of the soul, I mean if the soul dies when our flesh does? With this parable show that it isn't a death as we know is another kind of dead as the bible explains.

Comment: Your last two questions are irrelevant to the main question and story. Perhaps those should be asked in a new post or something?

Comment: This is too broad / primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off I'd like to state that this is, in my opinion, clearly not a parable because the Bible does not state it as one like it does in these many citations:

```
Matthew 13:18
Luke 6:39
Luke 12:16
Luke 15:3
Luke 18:1
Luke 18:9
Luke 19:11
```

> **If Jesus was speaking of reality then 'The End' had technically already come. Is this correct?**

So, to answer this question, Jesus was in fact not only speaking of reality but also of a real happening. Lazarus and the rich man was not a parable, it was real. However, `The End` has not yet come. In fact, Hell is going to be destroyed as well and is simply a holding place for the souls that are lost. Revelation speaks of it in Revelation 20:14:

> And death and hell were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death.

Note that both death (the fact that man must die for his sins) and hell are cast into the lake of fire. Furthermore, that is where the devil will end up according to Revelation 20:10:

> And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, where the beast and the false prophet are, and shall be tormented day and night for ever and ever.

So, the end has not yet come, but it's on its way.

> **From Hell it would appear we can see Heaven and speak to people in Heaven as they can see us.**

This now makes more sense now that we have revealed that hell is a holding place for souls, but let's concrete this a bit more and see clearly that heaven is a holding place for souls as well. So, let's look at Revelation 21:1:

> And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away; and there was no more sea.

Here we see that heaven, which is the holding place that Lazarus ascended to, is also destroyed and a new heaven and a new earth is built. So yes, those souls in hell can see those souls in heaven until both are destroyed.

> **It also states that there are gates to Heaven which again have people outside them. Can I assume then that Hell is basically everything outside of Heavens gates.**

I would say you don't assume that everything outside the gates of heaven is hell, the earth is outside the gates of heaven but is clearly defined as the earth in Genesis 1:1:

> In the beginning God created heaven, and earth.

So hell is a different creation all by itself.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! I must say, this is a great first answer! I hope you'll stick around. :)

Comment: Thanks @El'endiaStarman! I plan on sticking around! Blessings to you in the name of Jesus!

Comment: This is really a minority view among Christians.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I understand that, but if you'll read my division of the Word objectively I think you'll understand why I don't believe it's a parable. It's hard to swallow, and a good majority may reject it, but is my division of the Word not sound? Do you think God *forgot* to include the preface that it was a parable?

Comment: "hell is a different creation all by itself created when man sinned" - this contradicts your previous correct declaration (as a quote from Revelation) that indicates hell is thrown into the lake of fire because it was prepared for the "devil and his angels"

Comment: @BigM This site is about what Christians believe. You may personally disagree with them, and that is your right, but it's not really on topic here. (And for the record, no I don't agree with you).

Comment: @DJClayworth, it appears from this post and others of mine you dislike me, and that's really quite alright, but I'm not sure what you definition of Christians is. Clearly you believe I stand outside that camp, but quite the contrary. Remember, my answers may be in the minority, but Jesus fell in the same category with the Pharisees, you may remember when he spoke to 5,000 and all went away but twelve and even one of them was a devil. Do I come on too strong for you? What is it that you're looking for? Maybe only people who see the bible the way you do?

Comment: @DJClayworth, and what exactly gives you the impression that you know the majority vs. the minority? I mean I take it you've spoken to every person who calls themselves a Christian and ran some statistics on them surrounding every possible topic?

Comment: @warren, clearly he'll was not created during the formation of the world as it's not documented as such nor was it necessary until sin entered into the world. But Luke 10:18 shows where Satan fell like lightening from Heaven and so then a place would have needed to exist for him and his followers to go.

Comment: All, I know that this is hard to swallow, and it doesn't *feel* good to talk about Hell, but a significant number of souls will end up there. (Is 5:14; Mat 7:13)

Comment: However, that is why I try and reach all I can and do all I can to help people stay saved. I love all men and try to live peaceably with all, I want to see Jesus.

Comment: @BigM I'm sorry if I gave the impression I didn't like you. It's not the case. I certainly don't believe you "stand outside the camp". I'm very happy for you to hold your own view of the Bible, and happy for you to write about it here.

Comment: @BigM - just because it was not documented, does not mean it was done: lots of things about heaven and earth were not documented, but obviously are there :) .. the lake of fire was created separately for the devil and his angels - whether that was before the creation of earth (as most I personally know believe), or at some point later is unclear. However, it is clear that the topic is not touched-upon in the creation account, and presuming to know when it was done is dangerous.

Comment: @warren, point well taken. Let's assume we don't know when Hell was created, and that it doesn't matter because it wasn't mentioned, but what we do know is that it's a holding place that will be cast into the lake of fire.

Answer (score 3):

In this passage Jesus is telling a Parable. Parables are stories intended to make specific points. They are not descriptions of reality. They are not "true stories". If you try push them too hard you will lose the point that is being made. We have no reason to think that there actually was a person called Lazarus to whom this happened. There is no reason to assume from this passage:

- That Heaven actually has gates
- That "The End" has come. Jesus could be speaking about something that was going to happen in the future, or just describing a hypothetical interaction
- That people in Heaven and Hell can really interact

Nor can you say that "Hell is everything outside Heaven". Clearly we live in a place now which is neither. On the basis of other Christian doctrines it is true that *eventually* every *person* will be divided into those who are with God, and those who are not.

Comment: That being said if this Parable is correct then we could possibly assume that The Rich man knew Abraham how else would he call out to this one man.  I wouldn't know Abraham if I seen him walking the street.

Comment: Not everyone agrees this is a parable. It doesn't follow the typical form and is not introduced as such.

Comment: @TheMonkeyMan If it's a parable then there doesn't need to be an explanation for how the Rich Man recognized Abraham.

Comment: @AffableGeek In modern times almost everybody considers this a parable. Wikipedia has only a single webpage backing up their section on 'literal interpretations', and that's a webpage which on closer inspection doesn't itself believe in a literal interpretation - it just says that other people believe that. (And the page has animated flames - never a sign of a balanced, scholarly viewpoint).

Comment: @AffableGeek, thanks for bringing up the fact that not everybody believes it's a parable. In fact my answer clearly shows there's somebody out there that doesn't, me. Although there is a down voter out there somewhere too cowardly to comment. Which is funny to me because in an online forum you don't even really have to face me, but I digress.

Comment: I, also, have to take issue with declaring this to be a parable. While it certainly *could* be, there is nothing in the recounting that demands it.

Comment: This site is about what Christians believe. Christians in general consider this a parable. If you personally disagree that is your right, but not really on topic here.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that most English translations use the word "Hell" to describe two completely different things: "Hades" (the realm of the dead) and "Gehenna" (the lake of fire). Before Christ, there was no salvation. Jews that kept God's covenant went to a place called Paradise or Abraham's Bosom, while the rest went to Hades. As already mentioned, we are not told that this story is a parable like we are in the other parables (though that doesn't necessarily mean that it isn't). We cannot be certain if its a parable or not, and since we can't be certain about that, we also can't be certain if there was/is a way for people in Hades and Paradise to see and speak to each other.

Since "Hell" in this story is referring to Hades, we cannot infer 'the end' has come, since people were going to Hades since long before Christ. I believe your references to Revelation are speaking about the millennial reign of Christ on Earth. During this time Christ comes to rule the nations/world from Jerusalem. Hell is not outside Jerusalem, and Heaven is not inside. It is still just Earth.